# i want to display records in jtable from mysql

Tags: java, mysql

i want to display the records in jtable from mysql
my table contains four rows.
Username varchar,
Login timestamp,
Logout timestamp,
Status char.

```
   public class Secondpage extends javax.swing.JFrame {
   java.sql.Connection conn=null;
   java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   public Secondpage() throws SQLException{
   initComponents();
   conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/login?" + 
   "user=root&password=");
   update_table();
   }
   private void update_table(){

   try{
   String sql = "Select * from userlog";
   pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs =  pst.executeQuery();
   table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
   }
```

after run the program i had a error like this.

```
java.sql.SQLException:java.sql.Timestamp
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getTimestampFast(ResultSetRow.java:937)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ByteArrayRow.getTimestampFast(ByteArrayRow.java:130)
com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestampInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5946)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:5616)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getObject(ResultSetImpl.java:4594)
at net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(DbUtils.java:28)
```

Comment: check your driver manager link

Comment: i checked it dude.....nothing works

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); add before Drivermanager class

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Comment: @HackerHate dude i already put the above statement.but can't work

Comment: conn=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabasename","username","password");

Comment: dude am already put this statement

Comment: Can you share your snippet for elaborate your question.

Comment: i think errors are due to login and logout column in database.because  they are stored in time stamp to get the date and time.i cant know how to display this fields.i try to display other tables with the same program it runs that tables does not contains time stamp fields

Answer (score 0):

Check your connection URL.

```
conn=DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabasename","username","p‌​assword");
```